# broadcast to many viewers in WebRTC using node js and socket-io (one to many broadcasting)

Tags: node.js, sockets, webrtc

I just created an application using WebRTC with Socket-IO where users can do live video chat. It is working fine and As many users connect to application, they are showing to everyone.

What I need now is Single user start broadcasting and users choose the broadcaster and start viewing them. No video share for clients should be there.

Link to my Application is `https://218.248.64.73:8443/`

Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a media server into the mix of servers you are currently using. The purpose of this server will be to receive the video from the broadcaster and then spread it to whoever wants to subscribe on it.

If you plan on broadcasting the same content to thousands of people, then you will need to cascade the media servers one to another as well. If you are willing to have a bit of latency (lets say 10 seconds), then you can connect your WebRTC broadcaster to a media server and convert the content to HLS or Flash and then stream it out through a CDN.

Here's the gist of it: https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-live-broadcast-future/

For developing your own with open source, look at employing [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) or [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/).

For using commercial media servers, look at [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/), [Red5 Pro](https://red5pro.com/) or nanocosmos.

You can also use solutions such as [Vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io/), [TokBox](https://tokbox.com/) or [Phenix](https://phenixp2p.com/).

Bottom line - adding broadcast on top of 1:1 video chat is going to bump up your costs considerably, but definitely possible.

Comment: Dear Tsahi, Thanks for suggestion. First thing, I dont want any latency and also when broadcaster is live, I want to convert the video to HLS in parallel.